# Installing libwebp package in visual studio solution fails

Tags: visual-studio, nuget-package, nopcommerce, webp

Ok so I'm trying to implement webp support in to a solution of nopcommerce source code.

This is it [on nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/libwebp.v140/):

I have looked through the google docs about it [here](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/docs/api) but could not find anything explaining why the install fail.

In package manager console this is the output, but I'm not sure exactly how to fix it.

> PM> Install-Package libwebp.v140 -Version 0.5.0.2
>
> Attempting to gather dependency information for package
>   'libwebp.v140.0.5.0.2' with respect to project 'Presentation\Nop.Web',
>   targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1' Gathering dependency
>   information took 1.85 sec Attempting to resolve dependencies for
>   package 'libwebp.v140.0.5.0.2' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest' One or
>   more unresolved package dependency constraints detected in the
>   existing packages.config file. All dependency constraints must be
>   resolved to add or update packages. If these packages are being
>   updated this message may be ignored, if not the following error(s) may
>   be blocking the current package operation: 'KendoUIWeb 2014.1.318
>   constraint: jQuery (>= 1.9.1)' Resolving dependency information took 0
>   ms Resolving actions to install package 'libwebp.v140.0.5.0.2'
>   Resolved actions to install package 'libwebp.v140.0.5.0.2' Retrieving
>   package 'libwebp.v140 0.5.0.2' from 'nuget.org'. Retrieving package
>   'libwebp.v140.redist 0.5.0.1' from 'nuget.org'.   GET
>   https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/libwebp.v140/0.5.0.2/libwebp.v140.0.5.0.2.nupkg
>   Install failed. Rolling back... Package 'libwebp.v140.redist.0.5.0.1'
>   does not exist in project 'Nop.Web' Package
>   'libwebp.v140.redist.0.5.0.1' does not exist in folder
>   'C:\projects\website\packages' Executing nuget actions took 66.4 ms
>   Install-Package : Could not install package 'libwebp.v140.redist
>   0.5.0.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1', but the package does not 
>   contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible
>   with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Install-Package libwebp.v140 -Version 0.5.0.2
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Answer (score -1):

> Could not install package 'libwebp.v140.redist 0.5.0.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework.

That why you can't install the package.